# AudioManager Ringer Mode does not match phone's value

Tags: android, android-audiomanager, android-8.0-oreo, vibration

### TL;DR: `AudioManager.getRingerMode()` seems to be wrong a lot. Is this API just buggy, or outdated, or am I doing something wrong?

---

**Issues:**

- `AudioManager.getRingerMode()` values are inconsistent and do not match docs.
- AudioManager reports ringer on silent when in vibrate mode.
- Broadcast listener skips steps and goes from 0-2 without going to 1

[According to the Docs:](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#RINGER_MODE_NORMAL)

- **RINGER_MODE_NORMAL** - Ringer mode that may be audible and may vibrate. It will be audible if the volume before changing out of this mode was audible. It will vibrate if the vibrate setting is on.
- **RINGER_MODE_SILENT** - Ringer mode that will be silent and will not vibrate. (This overrides the vibrate setting.)
- **RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE** - Ringer mode that will be silent and will vibrate. (This will cause the phone ringer to always vibrate, but the notification vibrate to only vibrate if set.)

---

**However,** here is a video showing it reporting 0 when the device is in vibrate mode and skipping from 0 to 2 without going to 1.

[image]

---

#### Source code

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    val volumeChangeReceiver = object : BroadcastReceiver() {
        override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent?) {
            val audioManager = context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE) as AudioManager
            val ringerMode = audioManager.ringerMode

            textView.text = (textView.text?.toString() ?: "") + when (ringerMode) {
                AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT -> "$ringerMode: RINGER_MODE_SILENT\n"
                AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE -> "$ringerMode: RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE\n"
                AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL -> "$ringerMode: RINGER_MODE_NORMAL\n"
                else -> ""
            }
        }

    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()

        val intentFilter = IntentFilter()
        intentFilter.addAction(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_CHANGED_ACTION)
        registerReceiver(volumeChangeReceiver, intentFilter)
    }

    override fun onPause() {
        super.onPause()
        unregisterReceiver(volumeChangeReceiver)
    }
}
```

Comment: I have the same essue. Do you get this results on emulator, or on a real device? What Android version installed?

Comment: When phone ring mode is set silent or mute the output it gives on Android 6 is RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE and not RINGER_MODE_SILENT. The same is working fine on Android 9 and 10 but not on Android 6,